# Repeated Cavitation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

Consider the following situation : Suppose i have a powerful laser beam. I somehow manage to use it to vaporise 10cc of water from inside a pool(pond) almost instantly(within 1-2 s). Note: i mean that the water i vaporised was not from the surface but from inside its bulk(say 20 ft deep into the pond). This will create a vapor cloud inside the pond, where the water was. As the vapors escape(bubbling their way out), the low pressure region left behind will cause surrounding water to rush in releasing energy(thermodynamic cavitation). My question is whether this energy can again repeat the process i described, i.e vaporise the surrounding water etc. Will the effect gradually decrease? Or is this completely impossible from the start?

Comment: homework-and-exercises?

Comment: Not exactly @JohnRennie, I was thinking about this situation while studying cavitation. It's not a homework question. But i added the tag anyway to prevent unnecessary debate whether it is a homework question or not.

Answer (score 0):

Practicalities aside, say you succeeded in vaporizing a blob of water within a larger body of water. The bubble will rise at certain acceleration and reach a terminal speed. The speed of water moving around the rising bubble is of the same order of magnitude as its terminal velocity. Since you are studying cavitation you must know the kind of speeds that need to be reached before water cavitates. So a rising bubble will not succeed in causing cavitation.

If I understand your question right, you seem to be visualizing the process in two steps: first, a bubble is formed and immediately escapes from water body, and second, due to this rapid escape, a low pressure zone is created that induces rapid motion in surrounding water leading to cavitation. However water being to a very good approximation incompressible, water will almost instantaneously respond to a small pressure change, and will not wait around until pressure within itself has fallen to a substantially low value before it begins to rush in. This means that as soon as bubble begins to move, water also begins to move with no possibility of bubble leaving behind a low pressure zone that is sufficient to induce water to cavitate.

Comment: I was thinking about this as well.. I guess that's something i overlooked.